# GMapsFX Custom Marker Icons Do Not Display Correctly

Tags: google-maps, javafx, google-maps-markers

I am creating a simple map using GMapsFX. This map should display two markers with different icons: a red circle and a blue circle. However, when I attempt to run the code shown below, the same icon is used for both markers. This problem appears to resolve itself when I manually change the zoom, but not when I change the zoom using the GMapsFX zoom method.

**Images Showing Problem**

[Actual Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8rhN.png)

[Desired Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUDAq.png)

**Controller**

```
package map;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.MapComponentInitializedListener;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.GoogleMap;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.LatLong;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapOptions;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapTypeIdEnum;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.Marker;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MarkerOptions;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;


public class Controller implements Initializable, 
        MapComponentInitializedListener {

    @FXML
    protected GoogleMapView view;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {    
        view.addMapInializedListener(this);
    } 

    @Override
    public void mapInitialized() {    
        MapOptions options = new MapOptions();
        options
            .center(new LatLong(40.7127, -74.0059))
            .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP)
            .zoom(12);
        map = view.createMap(options);
        view.setKey("");
        showMarker(40.748433, -73.985656, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Disc_Plain_red.svg/32px-Disc_Plain_red.svg.png");
        showMarker(40.713, -74.0135, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Disc_Plain_blue.svg/32px-Disc_Plain_blue.svg.png");
    }

    /**
     * Adds a marker to the map.
     */
    public void showMarker(double lat, double lng, String iconPath) {
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options
            .icon(iconPath)
            .position(new LatLong(lat, lng));
        Marker marker = new Marker(options);
        map.addMarker(marker);
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView?>


<GoogleMapView fx:id="view" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="map.Controller" />
```

**Main Program**

```
package map;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MapTesting extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("map.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Window");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
String image = MarkerImageFactory.createMarkerImage("file:"+path, "png"); //or jpg
image = image.replace("(", ""); //fix an error of the API
image = image.replace(")", "")
options.icon(image);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.